# How to detect if the output of a function is assigned to an object in R

Tags: r

Inside an R function, is it possible to detect if the user has assigned the output to an object?

For example, I would like to print on console some information only if the output is not assigned to an object, I am looking for something like this

```
fun <- function(a){
           b <- a^2
           if(!<OUTPUT ASSIGNED>) cat('a squared is ', b)
           return(invisible(b))
}
```

So that the result on console would be different whether the function output is assigned or not, e.g:

```
> fun(5)
> a squared is 25
>
> out <- fun(5)
>
>
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think this capability exists. (I'd be really curious about it if it does, but can't think of any way to do it.)

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if I've completely thought this one through, but this seems to work for the example you've given. (Note it's important to use `=` or `assign` or `.Primitive("<-")` *inside* the `fun` you'd like to subject to this treatment.)

```r
fun <- function(a){
  b = a^2   # can't use <- here
  if (!identical(Sys.getenv("R_IS_ASSIGNING"), "true")) cat('a squared is ', b)
  return(invisible(b))
}

`<-` <- function(a, b) {
  Sys.setenv("R_IS_ASSIGNING" = "true")
  eval.parent(substitute(.Primitive("<-")(a, b)))
  Sys.unsetenv("R_IS_ASSIGNING")
}

fun(5)
#> a squared is  25
out <- fun(6)
out
#> [1] 36
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: In the second function, maybe it's safer to do `on.exit(Sys.unsetenv("R_IS_ASSIGNING"))` right after setting the variable and before `eval.parent`. Upvote, my favorite.

Comment: if you use `:=` you don't need to overwrite `<-` or be careful about not using it in your function

Comment: Is the `:=` operator defined by a package?

Answer (score 5):

If I correctly understand what do you need it's better to use custom print method:

```
print.squared_value = function(x, ...){
    cat('a squared is', x, "\n")
    x
}

fun = function(a){
    b = a^2
    class(b) = union("squared_value", class(b))
    b
}

fun(2)
# a squared is 4
```

UPDATE:

```
fun = function(a){
    b = a^2
    invisible(b)
}


h = taskCallbackManager()
# add a callback
h$add(function(expr, value, ok, visible) {
    # if it was a call 'fun' without assinment
    if(is.call(expr) && identical(expr[[1]], quote(fun))){
        cat('a squared is', value, "\n")    
    }

    return(TRUE)
}, name = "simpleHandler")

fun(2)
# a squared is 4
b = fun(2)
b
# [1] 4

# remove handler
removeTaskCallback("R-taskCallbackManager")
```

Comment: In this way, if I assign `obj<-fun(2)` and then type `obj` on the console I will get the message `a squared is 4`, while I would like to get just the value `4`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, this could do the trick:

```
fun <- function(a){
           b <- a^2
           if(sum(unlist(lapply(lapply(ls(envir = .GlobalEnv), get), function(x){ identical(x,a^2)})))==0) cat('a squared is ', b)
           return(invisible(b))
}
```

So:

`ls(envir=.GlobalEnv)` will return all objects in your global environment

`lapply(ls(envir = .GlobalEnv), get)`: will return a list with the content of all objects in your global environment

`lapply(lapply(ls(envir = .GlobalEnv), get), function(x){ identical(x,a^2)})`: will return a logical list checking if the content of any of all objects in your global environment is identical to the output of your function

`sum(unlist(lapply(lapply(ls(envir = .GlobalEnv), get), function(x){ identical(x,a^2)})))==0` if none of the content of any of all objects is identical to hte ouput of your function, then... cat!

I hope this helps you!
Best!

Comment: This looks like a decent solution and the most logical(in my opinion). I'll go offline now.

Comment: Sorry, I think I wasn't clear enough. I added an example of my desired output to explain it better. I don't want to detect if a value is already saved into an object. I would like to let the function know if its output will be assigned to an object. Thanks for your simple solution, however it doesn't work in my case.