# Include an object within a function only if it exists

Tags: r

I have a loop that needs to be executed; within which are 6 models.  The objects that those models are stored in then need to get passed into a function that executes an AIC analysis.  However, sometimes one of the models does not work, which then breaks the code for the AIC function because it does not recognize whatever model that failed because it was not stored as an object.

So, I need a way to pull those models that worked into the AIC function.

Here is an example, but keep in mind it is important that this can all be executed within a loop.  Here are three hypothetical models:

```
hn.1 <- ds(data) 
hn.1.obs <- ds(data,formula = ~OBSCODE) 
hn.1.obs.mas <- ds(dataformula = ~OBSCODE+MAS)
```

And this would be my AIC function that compares the models:

```
summarize_ds_models(hn.1, hn.1.obs, hn.1.obs.mas)
```

But I get an error if say, the hn.1.obs.mas model failed.

I tried to use "get" and "ls" and I successfully pull the models that exist when I call:

```
get(ls(pattern='hn.15*'))
```

But that just returns a character vector, so that when I call:

```
summarize_ds_models(get(ls(pattern='hn.15*')))
```

it only conducts the AIC analysis on the first model in the above character vector.

Am I on the right track or is there a better way to do this?

**UPDATE with a reproducible example.**

Here is a simplified version of my problem:

create and fill two data frames that will be put into a list:

```
data.frame <- data.frame(x = integer(4),
                         y = integer(4),
                         z = integer(4),
                         i = integer(4))
data.frame$x <- c(1,2,3,4)
data.frame$y <- c(1,4,9,16)
data.frame$z <- c(1,3,8,10)
data.frame$i <- c(1,5,10,15)

data.frame.2 <- data.frame[1:4,1:3]

my.list <- list(data.frame,data.frame.2)
```

create df to fill with best models from AIC analyses

```
bestmodels <- data.frame(modelname = character(2))
```

Here is the function that will run the loop:

```
myfun <- function(list) {

for (i in 1:length(my.list)){

mod.1 = lm(y ~ x, data = my.list[[i]])
mod.2 = lm(y ~ x + z, data = my.list[[i]])
mod.3 = lm(y ~ i, data = my.list[[i]])  

bestmodels[i,1] <- rownames(AIC(mod.1,mod.2,mod.3))[1]#bestmodel is 1st row  
}
  print(bestmodels)
}
```

However, on the second iteration of the loop, the AIC function will fail because mod.3 will fail.  So, is there a generic way to make it so the AIC function will only execute for those models that worked?  The outcome I would want here would be:

```
> bestmodels
  modelname
1     mod.1
2     mod.1
```

since mod.1 would be chosen for both AIC analyses.

Comment: Have you tried `exists()` to evaluate whether your models exist in the environment, and include those models where `exists() == TRUE` for your set of models?

Comment: You could store the models in a list and use `purrr::possibly` to wrap `summarise_ds_models` so it doesn't fail on error

Comment: Maybe `mget`?...

Comment: phalteman -- I was able to execute the first part of your suggestion, but how do I "include those models where exists() == TRUE" for the set of models?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if the output of a function is assigned to an object in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54731759/how-to-detect-if-the-output-of-a-function-is-assigned-to-an-object-in-r)

Comment: What is the expected behavior if only 2 out of 3 models are successfully made? Do you want to call `summarize_ds_models` with just those 2 models? Also, where is the `summarize_ds_models` function from? If it's something custom, you can rewrite it to accept a list of models or an indeterminate number of models using the  `...` argument.

Comment: divibisan -- Yes, if only 2 of the models work then I need to pass them to the "summarize_ds_models" function.  The function is from the "Distance" package and is not custom.

Comment: Use a `list` instead of individual named objects. Then `do.call(summarize_ds_models, my_list_of_models)`. If it isn't done already, you can `Filter` the list first to make sure only working models are in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gregor's comment:

Use a list instead of individual named objects. Then do.call(summarize_ds_models, my_list_of_models). If it isn't done already, you can Filter the list first to make sure only working models are in the list.

solved my problem.  Thanks